# Google-like search info for Emacs

Tags: search, emacs, full-text-search

Is there a package/function to search info pages from emacs similarly to web search? I mean you just give few words, and the emacs returns you all the pages with these words. The words can be in any order, maybe use fuzzy match etc., regexp does not help a lot in this case. The similar question is discussed in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SearchNear but I'm not satisfied with the solution. Does anybody know more general software?

Ideally, such kind of search should handle not only info pages, but any source, for example all open buffers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be looking for `info-apropos` which you can call with `M-x info-apropos`.  This performs a full-text search of the info files and returns a hyperlink list of sections containing the word.

I don't think that it does multiple words like a search engine, but it may get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[Anything.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) has a [configuration](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything-config.el) for searching Info pages. It's called `anything-c-info-pages` and looks like it searches for info topics, so it's not exactly what you want, but if you know elisp then you can copy this source and easily modify it to perform full text search instead.

If you don't know Anything then [here's an introduction](http://metasandwich.com/2010/07/30/what-can-i-get-for-10-dolla-anything-el/) and an other one about [creating your own sources](http://metasandwich.com/2010/08/01/anything-else/) for it.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not know elisp well, but maybe I'll try one day. thanks for references!

Answer (score -1):

For a more powerful and flexible alternative see [Emacs Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything). To fetch it do

```
git clone git://repo.or.cz/anything-config.git ~/anything-config
```

in your terminal. Then add the following code snippet to your Emacs configuration file `~/.emacs`:

```
(byte-recompile-directory "~/anything-config")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/anything-config" t)
(load "~/anything-config/anything.elc")
(load "~/anything-config/anything-config.elc")
```

Finally run it using `M-x anything`.

I prefer to bind it to Alt-X by adding the following line to `~/.emacs.`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-X") 'anything)
```

Comment: Does Anything have a source for full page info search? That is the question. You may want to provide such a source and that would answer the OP's question instantly.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I've already tried Anything. indeed, the sources should be configured as pointed out by Tom.